# How to get button id using onclick Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

i am working on Reactjs and using Nextjs, I am using "functional component" (not class),I have button inside loop and i want to get id of button using "onClick",But i am getting following error
this is undefined
Here is my current code

```
const deleteReview=async({currentTarget})=>
     {
        alert(currentTarget.value);
     }


{
    reviewfromserver.map(reviewnew=>{
        return(
                <div key={reviewnew.id}>
                    <div>{reviewnew.id}- {reviewnew.title} 
                        <button onClick={this.deleteReview} >Delete</button>
                    </div>
               </div>
              )
           })
}
```

Comment: @Andy i want to pass "{reviewnew.id}" with button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add an id to the button. Because you may have identical ids somewhere else in your page I would recommend adding it as a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes). You can then pick up the id from the element's data set in the handler.
2. You appear to be confusing calling class methods in a React class component with calling functions in a React function component. There's no need for `this` preceding the function name.
3. There's no reason for that handler to be `async`.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Example({ reviewfromserver }) {

  function deleteReview(e) {
    console.log(e.target.dataset.id);
  }

  return (
    <section>
      {reviewfromserver.map(reviewnew => {
        return (
          <div key={reviewnew.id}>
            <div>{reviewnew.id} - {reviewnew.title} 
              <button
                data-id={reviewnew.id}
                onClick={deleteReview}
              >Delete
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </section>
  );

}

const reviewfromserver = [
  { id: 1, title: 'One' },
  { id: 2, title: 'Two' },
  { id: 3, title: 'Three' },
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example reviewfromserver={reviewfromserver} />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

**Option 1:**

`bind` use it like this

```js
const deleteReview = async (id) => {
        alert(id);
}


{
    reviewfromserver.map(reviewnew=>{
        return(
                <div key={reviewnew.id}>
                    <div>{reviewnew.id}- {reviewnew.title} 
                        <button onClick={this.deleteReview.bind(this,reviewnew.id)} >Delete</button>
                    </div>
               </div>
              )
           })
}
```

**option 2**

Write two function:

```js
const deleteReview = async (id) => () => {
        alert(id);
}


{
    reviewfromserver.map(reviewnew=>{
        return(
                <div key={reviewnew.id}>
                    <div>{reviewnew.id}- {reviewnew.title} 
                        <button onClick={this.deleteReview(reviewnew.id)} >Delete</button>
                    </div>
               </div>
              )
           })
}
```